# Creating a basic pay now button for sagepay gateway

Tags: button, opayo

I have a client who has signed up for a sagepay account. His current website runs off wordpress 3.0 and currently doesn't have any sort of ecommerce functionality.

He's needing a button that lets users submit a deposit of £300 through sagepay (this amount never changes).
(Usually, I would suggest using paypal for something like this, but apparently due to the travel nature of his business, paypal won't let my client have a pro account)

I've looked at the method described in a similar thread on here back in March ([How Do I Make a SagePay BuyNow Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540321/how-do-i-make-a-sagepay-buynow-button)), but I'm not really sure how to implement this within a page on wordpress, not hugely knowledgeable on php bar basic template editing, so I got totally lost at the $PAYMENT_CRYPT part.

If anyone could provide the steps I need to take to implement a basic button that submits the same amount each time, and then collects all the card details/customer details once it's sent them to sagepay gateway, it would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. These is no easy way to approach this. Unless you link to a Payment form to SagePay and use the new IFRAME feature. You can have certain information within WordPress that allows PHP code on your template pages or your template files.

1 - IFRAME the form within your PHP server and code the form on its own that way the CSS will become like the CSS on the WordPress page

2 - Create a payment module for it

3 - Use an existing Payment eCommerce server module for WordPress - there are plenty of plugins already

4 - Create a payment button hyper link, once clicked, it goes to a PHP form on your server for the £300 amount..

5 - Use Nochex or another payment vendor, Google Wallet etc (this is not an easy option for the client)

With the FORM, you could have:

```
<? 

# Define your vars

$serverLive="https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp"
//$serverLive="https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp"
$YOUR_VENDOR_LOGIN_NAME="";
$VendorTxCode="406227821909";
$Amount="350.00";
$Currency="GBP";
$Description="1 ACME Widget";
$SuccessURL="http://example.com/success.php";
$FailureURL="http://example.com/fail.php";
$BillingSurname="Smith";
$BillingFirstnames="John";
$BillingAddress1="123 Main Street";
$BillingCity="Anywhere";
$BillingPostCode="29555";
$BillingCountry="USA";
$DeliverySurname="Smith";
$DeliveryFirstnames="John";
$DeliverAddress1="123 Main Street";
$DeliveryCity="Anywhere";
$DeliveryPostCode="29555";
$DeliveryCountry="GBP";

# The address information can be done via jQuery on your page or get some defaults

?>
<form action="<?=$serverLive?>" method="POST" id="SagePayForm" name="SagePayForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="VPSProtocol" value="2.23" />
    <input type="hidden" name="TxType" value="PAYMENT" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Vendor" value="<?= $YOUR_VENDOR_LOGIN_NAME ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Crypt" value="<?= $PAYMENT_CRYPT ?>">    
    <input type="image" src="images/buynow-sagepay.png" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.SagePayForm.submit();
}
submitform();
</script>
```

Even with this code you would still need to use some SagePay libraries, such as the XOR and Crypt functions:

```
// Crypt and XOR functions
private function simpleXor($string, $password) {
    $data=array();
    for ($i=0; $i < utf8_strlen($password); $i++) {
        $data[$i]=ord(substr($password, $i, 1));
    }
    $output='';
    for ($i=0; $i < utf8_strlen($string); $i++) {
    $output .= chr(ord(substr($string, $i, 1)) ^ ($data[$i % utf8_strlen($password)]));
    }
    return $output;     
}
```

Comment: your $serverLive should have ; after it, and you did not say how to include // Crypt and XOR functions